# Why is there no crash when assigning a member widget as the central widget in QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt, qobject, ownership-semantics

I wrote the following code, which doesn't provoke any error:

`main.cpp`

```
#include "main_window.hpp"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

`main_window.hpp`

```
#pragma once

#include "ui_main_window.h"

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsView>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        ui.setupUi(this);
        setCentralWidget(&view);
    }

private:
    Ui::MainWindowClass ui;
    QGraphicsView       view;
};
```

However, Qt documentation for `QMainWindow::setCentralWidget` says that

> Note: QMainWindow takes ownership of the widget pointer and deletes it at the appropriate time.

Shouldn't there be a crash on finishing app because of double deleting of `view`: by Qt's ownership model and by `~MainWindow()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work as written. The behavior is well defined.

The way Qt ownership works, every `QObject`-derived object keeps a list of the children it owns, as well as a pointer to its parent it is owned by. `QObject` destructor then does two things - it destroys all children, and also notifies its parent that it has been destroyed. In response to that, the parent removes this now-destroyed child from its list of owned objects.

In your example, when `MainWindow` object is constructed, the base class `QObject` constructor runs first, (then other base class constructos), and then constructors of data members, including `view`. The destruction proceeds in the reverse order: `view` is destroyed first, whereupon it notifies its owner `MainWindow` object (or rather, the `QObject` base class sub-object within `MainWindow`) to remove itself from the list. Then eventually `QObject` destructor runs, but by that time a pointer to `view` is no longer in the list.

By this mechanism, double deletion is avoided.